# How to determine which DNS server a user is using

Tags: dns

If I visit https://www.opendns.com/welcome/ then it tells me whether I'm currently using their services or not. How does it determine this?

Answer (score 1):

Their DNS servers will provide different answer for `www.opendns.com` then any other "regular" server.

If you ask Google DNS (or [any other](https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/www.opendns.com)), the answer is 67.215.92.**219**

```
[root@ ~]# dig www.opendns.com @8.8.8.8
...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.opendns.com.        446     IN      A       67.215.92.219
```

If you ask one of the OpenDNS servers, the answer is 67.215.92.**218**

```
[root@ ~]# dig www.opendns.com @208.67.222.222
...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.opendns.com.        30      IN      A       67.215.92.218
```

If you keep your current DNS servers, and add this line to your `hosts` file:

```
67.215.92.218 www.opendns.com
```

and then visit https://www.opendns.com/welcome/, they will thank you for using OpenDNS.

Comment: I can see how this allows a DNS-serving company to determine if you are using them, but what about the general case? Specifically what mechanisms can be used by an arbitrary web site to enumerate the DNS servers that you are using? It can be done, but how is it done?

Answer (score 1):

They are figuring out which DNS resolver you are using and whether it's one of theirs or not.

The way they are actually doing this is by inserting some kind of web beacon within their web page with a unique value that triggers your client to do a DNS lookup (like an img with a uniq hostname under a domain they control)

Then they have the nameserver for that beacon domain souped up to cross reference the uniq identifier with the nameservers client (a.k.a *your* resolver)

It's pretty easy to do with a pdns pipe backend.

You can see which resolver you are using at

http://www.myresolver.com

Or the "What is My DNS Resolver" function on http://www.easyWhois.com